# Is it possible using google calendar api (2.0) to do wildard queries for calendar events

Tags: google-calendar-api

I'm trying to query my google calendar for events (using the .Net version of google calendar api 2.0) that have a title that **contains** a given string. The only examples I can find show queries where an event title is **equal** to a given string.

Here's my code, which works but only shows me events where the event title equals "hol". I want to retrieve events that contain "hol" somewhere in the title. Is there a way to achieve this ?

Here's my code

```
        var query = new EventQuery()
        {
            Uri = uri
            , SingleEvents =true
            , StartTime = new DateTime(2011, 1, 1)
            , EndTime = new DateTime(2011, 12, 31)
            , NumberToRetrieve = 100
            , SortOrder = CalendarSortOrder.ascending
            , ExtraParameters = "orderby=starttime"
            , Query="hol"
        };

        // Tell the service to query:
        var eventFeed = calendarService.Query(query);
        foreach (EventEntry entry in eventFeed.Entries)
        {   
            foreach (var time in entry.Times)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(time.StartTime + " - " + entry.Title.Text + "\n");
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Total number of events in 2011: " + eventFeed.Entries.Count + "\n");
        Console.ReadKey();
```